# Complex Conjugation is non-holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

If I consider $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and denote $g(z)=\bar{z}$, then I can verify that:

- For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^*}$:

$$lim_{\lambda \to 0} \frac{g(z_0+\lambda)-g(z_0)}{\lambda}=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda}=1$$

- In other hand, if we consider $w \in i\mathbb{R^*}$:
  $$lim_{w \to 0} \frac{g(z_0+w)-g(z_0)}{w}=\frac{-w}{w}=-1$$
  So that, $g$ is not holomorphic at $z_0$.

But I could see in an identical manner that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial x}\neq -i(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})$, i.e., $$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\neq \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \quad or \quad  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\neq -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Hello, of course this is a good approach. Good job.

Comment: The second limit should be when $w \to 0$

Comment: Why did you ask this question? You gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not holomorphic.

On the C-R equations you get $f(x+iy)=x-iy\implies u(x,y)=x, v(x,y)=-y.$

So $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}=1\not=-1=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.$ and $\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}=0=-\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}.$

But at any rate it fails.